# Filling an String Array with a constructor from another class

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to programming in Java. We are assigned to create a MovieSeating class which is a 2D array. I am stuck on a part where I need to fill each "space" with the information of a customer from a class called Customer I have in another Java file.

```
 public Customer()//constructor
 {
      lastName = "???";
      firstName = "???";
      customerID = 0;
      matineeTickets = 0;
      normalTickets = 0;
      totalCost = 0.0;
  }
```

I am not sure how to take this info with multiple types and fill it into my 2d array.

Code I currently have, but stuck where to go from here. Keep getting errors for everything I try.

```
public class MovieSeating
{
//instance variables
private String [][] seating; //declare array


//create constructor to create Movie Seating array
public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum)
{

    seating = new String [rowNum][columnNum];

    //for loop to crate an initial customer elember for each part of 

    for (int r = 0; r<rowNum;r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columnNum; c++)
        {
            seating [r][c]= //????????????   
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any insight to set me on the correct path.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a `Customer[][]`?

Comment: Do you mean create a customer Array inside of the movie seat array?

Comment: What are you trying to assign and what errors do you get?

Comment: I tried initially to create a new customer object then assign it to the specified space seating[r][c]. So Customer cust = new Customer(); Then assigned seating [r][c] = cust;  but it tells me Customer cannot be converted to a String

Comment: Just to clarify each one of these spaces in the MovieSeating array represents a seat in the movie theater.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare your array like this:

```
Customer[][] seating;
```

And initialize it like this:

```
seating = new Customer[rowNum][columnNum];
```

Now you can just assign a new customer to each "space" in the array:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
// set fields of cust here...
seating[r][c] = cust;
```

I also recommend you to add a `toString` method in the `Customer` class. This way, you can still use a `String[][]` instead of a `Customer[][]`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // this is just an example, you can add more to the string.
    return "Last Name = " + lastName + ", First Name = " + firstName + ", Customer ID = " + customerID;
}
```

Now to assign a `Customer` to a `String[][]`, just call `toString`:

```
seating[r][c] = cust.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I did not know you could initialize a constructor to an array. Can you expand on why you declared Customer [][] seating; Would like to fully understand your thought process. Is it just declaring an array to be used on the Customer Class?

Comment: @Soaker Since you want to store the Customers in the array, you need to create an array that can do that. `Customer[][]` can only store customers, while `String[][]` can only store strings. @Soaker